# Django MultiValueField as Hidden_Input is not bound

Tags: django

I have a ModelForm to create/update a Course object. One of the fields in the form is 'faculty', which is a MultiValueField and has a many-to-many relationship with Course.

Creating and updating a Course (and associated faculty) was working fine, but now I want to make faculty a hidden field depending on some condition (called "updating") when the user is making an update. I handle this in CourseForm's **init** method. But when I set the widget to forms.HiddenInput() and then try to update Course, I see a validation error: "(Hidden field faculty) Enter a list of values". Even though faculty was assigned when the course was created, when I go to update the course, the form instance thinks faculty is empty. This seems to be specific to MultiValueField, since this process works for an IntegerField.

Do I need to set the value for the faculty field somehow? I'll show the relevant code below, if that's helpful. Thank you.

## models.py

```
 class Faculty(models.Model):
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

 class Course(models.Model):
    faculty = models.ManyToManyField(Faculty)
    term_num = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
```

## forms.py

```
class CourseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Course
        fields = ['term_num', 'faculty' ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        updating = kwargs.pop('updating', False)
        super(CourseForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if updating: 
            self.fields['faculty'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
```

## views.py

```
class CourseUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Course
    template_name = 'mcadb/course_form.html'
    form_class = CourseForm

    def get_form_kwargs(self, **kwargs):
        # pass data to form
        kwargs = super(CourseUpdate, self).get_form_kwargs(**kwargs)
        kwargs['updating'] = True
        return kwargs
```

Comment: That is because the faculty object is not set to null=True

Comment: @karthikr, I'm not sure I follow. Are you talking about the faculty field in the Course object? I have not set null=True on that because I don't want to allow a Course to be created without specifying a faculty. When the error is happening, is when the user is updating an existing course that does have a faculty.  The user is not allowed to edit the faculty, but is allowed to edit other fields (like term_num). So I want faculty to keep its original value, hidden from the user on the update form.

Comment: In that case, i would encourage you to have an Edit form which has `faculty` as an excluded field, instead of making it a hidden input.

Comment: OK, thanks, I'll try creating a separate Edit form, or maybe one that inherits, instead of putting the logic in the init method.

Comment: Creating a separate Edit form with its own set of fields works fine, avoids the original error, and as it turns out, saved a lot of code. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: As python says - explicit is better than implicit. Glad it helped.